# why does my serial print twice on Arduino IDE via Serial Monitor?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have only put in one 'print command' however I get two print reads.

The programme drives two stepper motors. 
The moveSteps value = 48

The motor stops briefly and print's '48' when the programme starts to run and then '48' again when the if is triggered, just before the programme ends.

Only one '48' should be printed. Any ideas why this happens?

```
 /*
  Precise movement with stop 

  Moves the robot 20mm forwards and 20mm backwards 

  Rob Miles (edited by Dileepa Ranawake)

  April 2017
  Version 1.0

 */

int motorDelay;

byte left1,left2,left3,left4;

byte right1,right2,right3,right4;

float wheelDiameter = 68.5;
float stepsPerRevolution = 512;
float mmsPerStep = (wheelDiameter * 3.1416) / stepsPerRevolution;

int moveCount;
int moveSteps;  // number of steps the motor is to move 

void leftForwards()
{
  left1=7; left2=6; left3=5; left4=4;
}

void leftReverse()
{
  left1=4; left2=5; left3=6; left4=7;
}

void rightForwards()
{
  right1=8; right2=9; right3=10; right4=11;
}

void rightReverse()
{
  right1=11; right2=10; right3=9; right4=8;
}

int calculateDistanceSteps(float distanceInMM)
{
  return distanceInMM / mmsPerStep + 0.5;
}

void setup() {
  leftForwards();  
  rightForwards();

  pinMode(left1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(left2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(left3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(left4,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(left1,HIGH);

  pinMode(right1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(right2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(right3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(right4,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(right1,HIGH);

  motorDelay=1200;

  moveCount=0;
  moveSteps = calculateDistanceSteps(20);
  Serial.begin(9800);

}

void loop() {

  moveCount = moveCount + 1;

  if (moveCount==moveSteps) 
  {
  digitalWrite(left1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(right1,LOW);
  Serial.println(moveCount);
  exit(0);
  }

  digitalWrite(left2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(right2,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(motorDelay);
  digitalWrite(left1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(right1,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(motorDelay);
  digitalWrite(left3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(right3,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(motorDelay);
  digitalWrite(left2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(right2,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(motorDelay);
  digitalWrite(left4,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(right4,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(motorDelay);
  digitalWrite(left3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(right3,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(motorDelay);
  digitalWrite(left1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(right1,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(motorDelay);
  digitalWrite(left4,LOW);
  digitalWrite(right4,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(motorDelay);

}
```

Serial Monitor prints out 4848

I have also noticed that just opening serial monitor makes the stepper motor move!

Comment: Couple of notes: `9800` is not a standard baud rate - `9600` is. When you open the serial monitor, your Arduino resets. And, calling `exit()` from an Arduino is also not standard.

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyMopp I've updated both - (replaced 9800 with 9600 and 'exit(0);' with 'return;' however I still get duplicate serial monitor readouts and now the motors continue running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `exit()` with an Arduino is not standard. It basically disables all interrupts and enters an infinite loop. You could restructure your `loop()` like this to avoid it:

```
void loop()
{
    // Still moving?
    if (moveCount < moveSteps) {
        moveCount = moveCount + 1;

        // Move complete
        if (moveCount == moveSteps) 
        {
            digitalWrite(left1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(right1,LOW);
            Serial.println(moveCount);
        }
        else {
            digitalWrite(left2,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(right2,HIGH);
            //etc.....
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your loop delays 1200µs 8x. That's only 1200 × 8 = 9600 µs = 9.6 ms. If `moveSteps = 48` then the entire loop will only take 460.8 ms. The program is running once before you open the serial monitor then a second time after. What happens if you push the reset button after you've opened the Serial Monitor?

Have you considered using the Arduino's built in [Stepper Library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/stepper)?

Lastly, in the future, consider posting questions like this at [[arduino.se]](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks @johnny Mopp - that makes sense, when I press reset the program only runs once (and returns one value). 

I have heard about the libraries though I'm quite new to coding so I wanted to do it the long way so I undertand the hardware component + what the software is doing / practice writing functions etc.

Thank you for the link to arduino.se - didn't realise that was even a thing! 

I appreciate your help.

Dee